# Incorrect sender email address shows in the mail send using smtp phpmailer

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I am using PHP Mailer library to send mail. Here I set from email address. But that email does not show in the mail.

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = env("GMAIL_SMTP_DEBUG");

$mail->isSMTP();                                            
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   
$mail->Username   = "mygroup@gmail.com"
$mail->Password   = "******";                               
$mail->SMTPSecure = env("GMAIL_SMTP_SECURE"); 
$mail->Port       = env("GMAIL_SMTP_PORT");                          
$mail->ContentType = 'text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n';
$mail->WordWrap    = 900; 
//Recipients

$mail->Sender = "myemail@gmail.com";
$mail->SetFrom("myemail@gmail.com", "My Name",false);
.......
```

Here I want to receive from address is "myemail@gmail.com". But instead of I am getting "mygroup@gmail.com"

Comment: So, you are logging into GMail with one account, and trying to send mail from another?! I'm pretty certain that won't work

Comment: Yes delboy. But that is our group mail id. we are in the group. It is used to support team.

Comment: If we send using normal php mail(......,"-f"."myemail@gmail.com") .. then it will work.

Comment: When I check my code I see SetFrom is setFrom (Lowercase s) maybe thats the problem

Comment: No. Its not an issue

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is effectively forgery, and gmail (along with other services) doesn't allow it - it will substitute your account address instead, as you're seeing.

The one thing you can do is set up fixed aliases for your account in your gmail settings, and you can then use those as from addresses, and gmail won't substitute them. Even with this, it still won't let you use arbitrary from addresses on the fly - you have to define them beforehand.

Comment: Yes we can add aliases. But its our own group mail only.

Comment: If it's always the same group address, the alias should work just fine.

Comment: I don’t know what you mean

Comment: The current result is "Myname <mygroup@gmail.com>". But it should come as "Myname <myemail@gmail.com>"

Comment: OK, you'll have to ask gmail support beyond this - PHPMailer is doing everything it can. You can confirm what it's doing by setting `SMTPDebug = 2`, which will let you be sure that it's using the correct address in the `MAIL FROM` command.

Comment: We will get response text from smtp server if we use SMTPDebug = 2.

Comment: Yes, that’s what it’s for.

Comment: Do we need to change this SMTPDebug = 2 ?

Comment: As you like - it’s just for showing you debug output while you’re working on it. Turn it off when you’re ready to use it in production.